# Get memory usage for page that includes webworkers with puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer

I am trying to profile the memory usage on a data-intensive app that we're making using puppeteer. The app uses webworkers. From what I can tell, both window.performance.memory (browser API) and page.metrics (a puppeteer API) produce only the main thread memory.

I am basically looking for peak memory usage (summing main and worker ideally). I have tried also running the puppeteer job with `/usr/bin/time -v ...` but I don't think this captured the memory accurately either

Any recommendations welcome